# Has anyone else encountered ExecutionContext error for annotation validation from symfony 2.4 to 2.5?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-2.4, symfony-2.5

> ... must be an instance of Symfony/Component/Validator/ExecutionContext, instance of Symfony/Component/Validator/Context/LegacyExecutionContext given ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source, you can see it is deprecated since V2.5. You will indeed have to use `ExecutionContext` :

https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/2.5/Context/LegacyExecutionContext.php#L25

> @deprecated Implemented for backwards compatibility with Symfony < 2.5.
> To be removed in Symfony 3.0.